# TextButton default color in dark theme

Tags: android, material-components-android

Trying to change the default color for all TextButtons in my Android app w/ material.  I see that I can style a "materialButtonStyle" and "materialButtonOutlinedStyle".  However I do not see an attribute for a text button, possible something like "*materialButtonTextStyle*"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
  <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/myButton</item>
  <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/myButtonOutlined</item>
</style>
```

Example button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:text="Text Button" />
```

Is it possible to change the style globally for all material text buttons?

**EDIT:** Tried this from the theming-buttons material docs.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
  <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_purple_600</item>
</style>
```

However still not styling the text color for all text buttons.

Comment: when you say does not apply to all, does that mean that it is applied to some but not others?
can you add a sample of each button (one which works and one which does not?

Comment: @mohsensameti, it does not apply to any text buttons unless I specifically add the style to an individual button.  Is "borderlessButtonStyle" the right style to override?  If not is there a style I can override in my theme to style all text buttons within the app?

Comment: yes `borderlessButtonStyle` is correct, the thing is that a button becomes a textButton if you apply `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton` style or `borderlessButtonStyle` attribute. so you need to use the attribute on all of tour buttons. although you may be able to subclass materialButton and in the constructor read the value from this attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Buttons -Material design](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button) documentation the `TextButton` has a default style theme attribute `?attr/borderlessButtonStyle` which can be used in the AppTheme to change the style globally for all material text buttons.

To change the Text Colour globally for all TextButtons:

1.Define the `borderlessButtonStyle` attribute in the Light and Night AppTheme like the below:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
</style>

<!-- For TextButton-->
<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
  <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton" parent="">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

2.In every TextButton xml layout define the style `style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` like the below:

```
<Button
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/text_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Button" />
```

And the Text colour will be changed globally based to the `colorPrimary` which is defined in Light/Night Theme.

Following the same way you can achieve the same for the other Material Button Styles like `OutlinedButton` and the default `Button` like:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
    <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>


<!-- For TextButton-->
<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>

<!-- For OutlinedButton-->
<style name="Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.OutlinedButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
</style>

<!-- For Button -->
<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
</style>
```

And each `Button` listens to the above global attributes:

```
<Button
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/text_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Button" />

<Button
    style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
    android:id="@+id/outlined_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Outlined Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/default_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Default Button" />
```

Below is a sample result for each Button Style in Light mode:

[image: light_mode]

And below is a sample result for each Button Style in Night mode:

[image: dark_mode]

Comment: I mean yeah that will work, but material docs here https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button state to use @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton as the style.  So it would seem that although material devs correctly added "materialButtonStyle" and "materialButtonOutlinedStyle", they forgot to add "materialTextButtonStyle"

Comment: @lostintranslation yes the documentation its a bit confusing. The Text button section gives an example of how to style a specific Text button only using the style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" but the example in the Outlined button section shows two variations one with style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle" which is used in the app theme to affect all the outlined buttons and one example with style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon" which affects the specific outlined Button only.

Comment: But if you check at the end of the Text button section it says: “Default style theme attribute: ?attr/borderlessButtonStyle” which is the attribute needed to be used in the app theme to affect all TextButtons. Same in outlined button section at the end says “Default style theme attribute: ?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle”. But you are right the documentation its a bit confusing.

Comment: great point! Thanks for taking the time to answer and go back and forth with me.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [`textButtonColors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ButtonDefaults#textButtonColors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)), [TextButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TextButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.material.ButtonElevation,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.material.ButtonColors,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) use the primary color of your `MaterialTheme` as default content color.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun textButtonColors(
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    disabledContentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        .copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)
): ButtonColors = DefaultButtonColors(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    contentColor = contentColor,
    disabledBackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    disabledContentColor = disabledContentColor
)
```

To achieve your goal, if you don't change your primary color, you can define a custom theme and override the style of your text buttons.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomTextButtonStyle(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = MaterialTheme.colors.copy(
            primary = Color.Green // Set your custom color
        )
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
CustomTextButtonStyle() {
    TextButton(onClick = { }) {
        Text(text = "Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup that works for that one button.  I would like to change the text color style of all TextButtons in application.  I also get that the TextButton color is the primaryColor, however I have a dark primary color, and a dark text color on a button is not great.  Also sorry, looking for non compose solution, I removed the compose tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In the title it says you want to define *textColor* for a dark theme. Did you define the theme in `values-night` so your app will take these values if the phone is in dark mode.

Comment: Yes, the theme above is in values-night

Comment: I think then you have to set your defined style `@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton` to each Button instead of `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton` to apply your individual TextStyle, or do I misunderstand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Possibly, but the reason I am still looking for an answer to style all text buttons is that nothing else in theming/styling works this way.  For example I can define buttonStyle and buttonOutlineStyle for all buttons and outline buttons in the app.  However for TextButton's this style override is missing.  Makes me think I am missing something or have something wrong.

Comment: I cannot find a reference in the Android values for (Material)TextButtons, but maybe we are both missing something :D